# cargar ventana modal al cargar la pagina

Tags: php, javascript, html, web

Estoy tratando de que se abra mi ventana modal al entrar a mi web pero no consigo que funciona.

Poniéndole un botón y dándole click encima si consigo que se abra.
Alguna sugerencia? alguna idea que pueda probar?

Os dejo el código:

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal" role="dialog" >
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-full" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <center><h5 class="modal-title">HP LaserJet Pro M402dne</h5></center>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body p-4" id="result">
                    <center><h5>Ofertaa ofertaaaaa ofertaaaaaaa, llevate esta gangaa muchacho!!<br>Oferta exclusiva para este mes de mayo!</h5></center>
                 <!-- Product Detail -->
  <div class="container bgwhite p-t-35 p-b-80">
    <div class="flex-w flex-sb">
      <div class="w-size13 p-t-30 respon5">
        <div class="wrap-slick3 flex-sb flex-w">
          <div class="wrap-slick3-dots"></div>

          <div class="slick3">
            <div class="item-slick3" alt="impresora"  data-thumb=<?php print $Imagen ?>>
              <div class="wrap-pic-w">
                <img alt="IMG-PRODUCT" src=<?php print $Imagen ?> >
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

script que uso:

```
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function()
   {
      $("#myModal").modal("show");
   });
</script>
```

La consola me muestra estos fallos:

http://prntscr.com/nmcugj
http://prntscr.com/nmcus0
Muchas gracias a todos por la ayuda !
Un saludo

Comment: Te da algún error de consola? Podrías ser que se ejecute antes el js que el html.

Comment: actualizo la pregunta con el error de la consola

Comment: Te falta añadir la librería de jquery para poder usar $

Comment: gracias Iñigo! la librería estaba pero detrás del script , entonces no funcionaba el $, ya me funciona!

Comment: perfecto! me alegro.

Answer (score 0):

prueba poniendo el siguiente código entre las etiquetas  de tu código

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".modal").hide(0).delay(0).fadeIn(2000)
        });
    </script>
```